# Avoid new line before closing bracket

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

It is common with TypeScript to have constructors like this :

```js
export class SlotController {

  /*
   * This injects the dependency and assigns it to a field
   * It is NOT an unused variable
   */
  constructor(private service: SlotService) {}

  [...]
}
```

Unfortunately, upon automatic reformat, IntelliJ/WebStorm will add a new line before the closing curly bracket :

```js
constructor(private service: SlotService) {
}
```

I tried these options under `Code Styles > TypeScript` but it does not seem to work

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to enable the following options:

- Simple blocks in one line
- Simple methods in one line

Under `Settings/Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting`